# Change the default Category selection from a checkbox to an optionbox

Tags: categories

Is there any way to transform the default "Category" taxonomy menu in the admin panel (once in a post) from a checkbox multi-option to a checkbox single option, or an option box.

My aim is to prevent a user to add a content in more than one category.

Thanks

Comment: a "checkbox single option" is a radio.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on the duplicate. I wasn't able to find a matching document in first instance.